# In SSRS, when my value is NaN, how do I use that in an expression?

Tags: reporting-services

My dataset in the report is using an MDX query and I cannot change that query (don't even know how to; it was written by someone else). The MDX Query is outputting a decimal value for the field in question, and I am formatting it as a percent in the report. In some cases this field's value is NaN (before and after formatting).

This report contains an expression that changes the background color of that report cell to red if the value is over 0% Here is the formula:
=IIf(FormatPercent(Fields!Payment_Amount_Difference.Value) > FormatPercent(0) and Fields!Campaign_Year.Value >= 2016, "Red", "white")

This is working great except for when the value is NaN. The background color of NaN is red and I have been asked to make that not happen.

I have tried IsNumeric, but NaN is being perceived as numeric (I tested this by adding an additional column to the report and using an iif function to say "if numeric then yes, if not no").

I tried IsNothing also and that doesn't work. Tried "NaN" as a string in the expression and that also failed.

Any ideas for changing NaN to something else inside the report or adjusting my background color expression? The goal is for a field containing NaN to have a white background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used it but you can try the `IsNaN` .Net function.

```
=IIF(Fields!Campaign_Year.Value >= 2016 AND 
    IIF(Double.IsNAN(Fields!Payment_Amount_Difference.Value), 
        0.0, 
        Fields!Payment_Amount_Difference.Value
        ) 
     > 0, 
        "MistyRose", 
        "White", 
    )
```

Also, you don't need the FORMATPERCENT for the numbers to compare them. And I prefer something a little subtler than Red.

Comment: This led me down the right path. I created a nested iff statement where I used Double.IsNAN to evaluate the NaN first. The next piece of the expression evaluated if the value was over 0% and 2016 or later.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this against `NaN` but this might work.

```
=IIf(VAL(Fields!Payment_Amount_Difference.Value) > 0 and Fields!Campaign_Year.Value >= 2016, "Red", Nothing)
```

All I've done here is remove the FormatPercent function, as others have said - there is no need for it when comparing numbers to numbers. I then used `VAL` to convert the field to a value even if it contains a string.

I've never used this to try to convert `NaN` to zero before and I'm not in a position to test right now but it should work.

I also swapped out "White" for `Nothing` this is the default background for a textbox (basically transparent).